# Redirect on click of an image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to have a redirect on click of an image, but nothing happens.
Can anyone please guide me.

```
 <img src="img/facebook.png" style="border:0px;margin:2px;padding:2px;left;width:26px; height:20px;" onclick="window.location.href('https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gr81');"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, the following woked:

```
<img src="img/facebook.png" style="border:0px;margin:2px;padding:2px;left;width:26px; height:20px;" onclick="javascript:window.location='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gr81';" />
```

What I put in the `onclick` was

```
onclick="window.location='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gr81';"
```

The way to assign a [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) to a [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) property is by

```
window.location = "some url";
```

instead of

```
window.location('some url'); //incorrect
```

You could also do `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`, which seems like what you wanted to do in your code.

Answer (score 2):

if you can wrap the image with an anchor tag around then you can simply do

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/blah">
<img src="img/facebook.png" style="border:0px;margin:2px;padding:2px;left;width:26px; height:20px;" />
</a>
```

### Or a cleaner way would be to use a class name and jquery.

Now you have:

- in the `<head>` or a .css include

  `<style>.fbicon{border:0px;margin:2px;padding:2px;width:26px;height:20px;}</style>
  </head>`

your image in the body

```
<img src="img/facebook.png" class="fbicon"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.fbicon')(function() {
  //alert( "go to site" );
  window.location='https://www.facebook.com/blah';
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Unless the OP's already using jQuery, this seems like a lot of libraries for a simple function

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way

```
<img src="img/facebook.png" style="border:0px;margin:2px;padding:2px;left;width:26px; height:20px;" onclick="window.location='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gr81'"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the DOM (Document Object Model), the WINDOW object represents an open window in a browser. It has a "location" property that you can call and give it a value of your desired redirect URL like this:

```
<script>
    $('.fbicon').click(function() {
       window.location='https://www.facebook.com/blah';
    });
```

**Yet another example without JQUERY:**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Take me to CNN.com</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.href = "http://www.cnn.com";
}
</script>
```

**See these URLs for DOM element properties and values:**
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: I updated the code with explanation provided for all people to understand and URL to resources